# Xamarin label text max characters count on display

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, character

On exact font, How can I detect on xamarin, the maximum characters amount which can fill the device display.
For example [In this device maximum characters count is 2000 (for example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOb9y.png)

Comment: you can't, because with a proportional font the number of characters that can fit will depend on the exact text being displayed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in its current form, its impossible. Could be reworded to specify use of a non-proportional font. But I recommend instead stepping back: **Why** do you want to do that?